# Javascript Regex (replace) Issue

Tags: javascript, regex, replace

I am checking a collection and replacing all

```
<Localisation container="test">To translate</Localisation>
```

tags with text.

The next codes does what I want:

```
var localisationRegex = new RegExp("(?:<|&lt;)(?:LocalisationKey|locale).+?(?:container|cont)=[\\\\]?(?:['\"]|(&quot;))(.+?)[\\\\]?(?:['\"]|(&quot;)).*?(?:>|&gt;)(.*?)(?:<|&lt;)/(?:LocalisationKey|locale)(?:>|&gt;)", "ig");

            match = localisationRegex.exec(parsedData);

            while (match != null) {
                var localeLength = match[0].length;

                var value = match[4];

                parsedData = parsedData.substr(0, match.index) + this.GetLocaleValue(value) + parsedData.substr(match.index + localeLength);

                match = localisationRegex.exec(parsedData);
            }
```

But, when the the string I replace with, Is longer then the original string, the index/place where it will start to search for the next match, is wrong (to far). This sometimes leads to tags not found.

Comment: Please post a problematic input/replace combo so that we could reproduce the error.

Comment: The constructs ".+?" and "[\\\\]" confuse me. Also why wouldn't you use native regex syntax for something that complicated?

Comment: Actually now that I think about it, all of those ".+" and ".*" subexpressions are going to eat up all sorts of text. If you have two of those tags on the same line, for example, those will consume as much text as they can.  Parsing XML/HTML with regular expressions is a bad idea for that very reason. (Well, that reason, and others.)

Comment: Oh wait never mind; durr.  I haven't had any coffee yet :-)

Answer (score 0):

Setting aside the (important) question as to whether the approach is a good one, if it were me I'd avoid the problem of indexing through the source text by using a function argument to the regex:

```
var localizer = this;
var result = parsedData.replace(localisationRegex, function(_, value) {
  return localizer.GetLocaleValue(value);
});
```

That will replace the tags with the localized content.